# Is there a way to keep extension settings in selenium instance (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

Every time I run my program with a chrome extension I have to re-enter my settings. Is there a way that I can keep my settings rather than having to manually enter them each time?
(Current Driver Setup)

```
PATH = "/Users/devinhadley/Desktop/chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
ua = UserAgent(use_cache_server=False)
userAgent = ua.random
print("Fake UserAgent Generated")
chrome_options.add_extension('Buster.crx')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do your settings once without any code, fully manually. Then start your browser as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\')
PATH = "/Users/devinhadley/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
```

With this, you start Chrome with your profile and not with a new one. This should work :-)